# Android JSON Push Notification with Parse.com

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement my first JSON push notification with Parse.com, I've implemented the regular push notification and it worked properly. What I'm missing here that I can't find a complete guide how can I accomplish my goal. I'm trying to send a JSON notification through Parse.com console includes a URL that needs to be opened when push clicked.

Hereunder my manifest for regular push:

```
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.dubs.gamingmaster.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.xxx.xxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also Hereunder the Application class:

```
 import com.parse.Parse;
 import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
 import com.parse.ParseUser;
 import com.parse.PushService;

 public class Application extends android.app.Application {

   public Application() {
   }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

// Initialize the Parse SDK.
Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


// Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
       PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);



    }
   }
```

Comment: I've managed to solve this myself!! Thanks!

Comment: How did You solve? Please Answer Your Own Question so me and others can get help from it.